# swagger-ui-express Multiple Routes for Different API Documentation

Tags: node.js, express, routes, swagger-ui

I have 2 separate swagger API documentations which I want to run via swagger-ui-express NPM package, and my express server is starting fine on port 5000, but when I am trying to access any of the URL always getting the 404 error, Here is my app.js file and URL's for your reference:

Route 1: http://localhost:5000/edi 
Route 2: http://localhost:5000/ecom

```
const express    = require('express');
const router     = require('express').Router();
const swaggerUi  = require('swagger-ui-express');

const ediSwaggerDocument  = require('./edi-openapi.json');
const ecomSwaggerDocument = require('./ecom-openapi.json');

const SWAGGER_APP_PORT = process.env.SWAGGER_APP_PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

// Route Middleware to be called before serving Any Route
router.use('/', swaggerUi.serve); 

// Route - EDI RESTful API Documentaion 
router.get('/edi', swaggerUi.setup(ediSwaggerDocument)); 

// Route - eCommerce RESTful API Documentaion 
router.get('/ecom', swaggerUi.setup(ecomSwaggerDocument));

app.listen(SWAGGER_APP_PORT, () => console.log(`RESTful API Up and Running on Port ${SWAGGER_APP_PORT}`));
```

Comment: can you please provide your configuration files

Comment: @luvcoding Did you get the solution for that?

Answer (score 8):

Try the following configurations to hook `swaggerUi` with `express-app`

```js
app.use("/edi", swaggerUi.serve, (...args) => swaggerUi.setup(ediSwaggerDocument)(...args));
app.use("/ecom", swaggerUi.serve, (...args) => swaggerUi.setup(ecomSwaggerDocument)(...args));
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't dig enough into the `swagger-ui-express` but i think the problem comes from the function `generateHTML` (called in `swaggerUi.setup`). A global module variable (`swaggerInit`) is updated when called.

So the last call to `generateHTML` has side effects on every routes that use `swaggerUi.setup` middleware.

A quick fix is to generate HTML each time the route is called. According to the code snippet you provide, it should looks like :

```
 let swaggerDocEdi = require('./edi-openapi.json');
 let swaggerDocEcom= require('./ecom-openapi.json');
 let router = express.Router();

 router.use('/api/edi', swagger.serve, (req, res) => {
     let html = swagger.generateHTML(swaggerDocEdi);
     res.send(html);
 });

 router.use('/api/ecom', swagger.serve, (req, res) => {
     let html = swagger.generateHTML(swaggerDocEcom);
     res.send(html);
  });
```

*Note that the global variable is still updated.*

Answer (score 1):

```
router.use('/jobs/api/:id',swaggerUi.serve,(req,res)=>{
console.log("here")
let a = req.params.id
if(a==='all'){ res.status(200).send(swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerDocument))}
if(a==='google'){res.status(200).send(swaggerUi.generateHTML(GoogleAds)) }
```

});

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: it's not working... still it redirecting into the default swagger url

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a solution for this issue, and found a better solution recommended by Swagger UI Express. check the link below

https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express#two-swagger-documents

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocumentOne = require('./swagger-one.json');
const swaggerDocumentTwo = require('./swagger-two.json');

var options = {}

app.use('/api-docs-one', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocumentOne, options), swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocumentOne));

app.use('/api-docs-two', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocumentTwo, options), swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocumentTwo));
```

Hope this will help others as well.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `Router` is being used incorrectly. For this simple use case I would recommend adding your routes directly to the `app` instance. See:

```
const express    = require('express');
// xxxx const router     = require('express').Router();
const swaggerUi  = require('swagger-ui-express');

const ediSwaggerDocument  = require('./edi-openapi.json');
const ecomSwaggerDocument = require('./ecom-openapi.json');

const SWAGGER_APP_PORT = process.env.SWAGGER_APP_PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

// Route Middleware to be called before serving Any Route
app.use('/', swaggerUi.serve); // replaced router with app

// Route - EDI RESTful API Documentaion 
// REPLACED "router" with "app"
app.get('/edi', swaggerUi.setup(ediSwaggerDocument)); 
// Route - eCommerce RESTful API Documentaion 
// REPLACED "router" with "app"
app.get('/ecom', swaggerUi.setup(ecomSwaggerDocument));

app.listen(SWAGGER_APP_PORT, () => console.log(`RESTful API Up and Running on Port ${SWAGGER_APP_PORT}`));
```

Now, you could use the `Router` by adding it to the `app` instance with `app.use()`. See:

```
// Route - EDI
router.get('/edi', swaggerUi.setup(ediSwaggerDocument)); 

// Route - eCommerce 
router.get('/ecom', swaggerUi.setup(ecomSwaggerDocument));

// Adding it to App instance
app.use('/swagger', router)

// End Point =>     localhost:5000/swagger/edi
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I have already tried it. In that case it's just showing the blank page (when replace route with app), getting http 304 error. Configuration files edi_openapi.json and ecom_openapi.json are too big and can't paste to comments due to size limitation