# Exposing two swagger Open api specs on same nodejs server via two different urls

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I like to expose two different swagger specs e.g. internal.json and external.json on node js server using swagger-ui-express npm package.

I have followed the instruction given https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express and any one of the swagger works with below code.

```
const express = require("express");
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const internalSpec = require('../../swagger/internal.json');
const externalSpec = require('../../swagger/external.json');

module.exports = function (app) {
    const router = express.Router();

    router.use('/', swaggerUi.serve);
    router.get('/', swaggerUi.setup(internalSpec));

    app.use("/apispec", router);
};
```

But if I use router.get('/external', swaggerUi.setup(externalSpec)); again to access second Spec via ../apispec/external/ I can see the externalSpec in both /apispec & as well as /apispec/extenal urls. I suppose, swaggerUi.setup() of swagger-ui-express package creates a singleton instance of Swagger which overwrites earlier set up.

I tried another similar questio [swagger-ui-express Multiple Routes for Different API Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273857/swagger-ui-express-multiple-routes-for-different-api-documentation) , but this does not have answer yet.

Any solution please ?